# How do I remove this stubborn search icon from my site's top bar?

Tags: css, wordpress

So there seems to be a stubborn search button icon in the top bar of the staging site of my site but the problem is there is no turn-off or turn-on button for the icon in the admin area. I just can't seem to have it removed.

I believe I can remove this using CSS but I don't know how to.

The site I need help with is: (removed)

Comment: Use devtools to find information about the icon and remove it from the source.

Comment: Share the url ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the html code, simply remove the div with the class "main-search gva-search".

*Or, in your css add:*

```
.main-search{
display: none;
}
```

Note, that this causes the entire class to hide. If you want to only hide that certain element, give it an Id and hide it in CSS the same way, except with # instead of .

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS rule to your *template.css* file:

```
.topbar .header-right .main-search {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The file is located at */staging/wp-content/themes/oxpitan/css/template.css*

Answer (score 0):

Open inspect from chrome and get its id or unique class then add this css code to remove it

```
   class or id {display:none!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove that from your theme it must be in the **header**

note: if you use **display:none;** it still loads but it cannot be seen, if you dont need it at all just delete it.

open the header and search for below codes and delete them.

```
<div class="main-search gva-search open">
                <a class="control-search search-open"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                <div class="gva-search-content search-content">
                  <div class="search-content-inner">
                    <div class="content-inner"><form method="get" class="searchform gva-main-search" action="https://sundaybasilagbalegacyfoundation.com/staging/">
    <div class="gva-search">
        <input name="s" maxlength="40" class="form-control input-large input-search" type="text" size="20" placeholder="Search...">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-large btn-search">
            <input type="submit" class="fa" value="">
        </span>
    </div>
</form>


</div>  
                  </div>  
                </div>
              </div>
```